# How to configure XAMMP server to work for sending email?

Tags: php, email, xampp

Greet to all,

I set up the XAMMP server and install open source application like Osticket same configuration working on online hosting, but not with me please help me how to setup my localhost server to be able for sending an email and work as online?

Your support is appreciated!

regards, 
Atef

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't send email with php mail function on windows 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30610387/cant-send-email-with-php-mail-function-on-windows-8) and [How to configure xampp to send email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30519727/how-to-configure-xampp-to-send-email)

Comment: All tested applied but not able to fix could you please help me!